# Are assignment operators not overloaded, when called upon pointers of a base class?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

I have encountered the following problem which proved to me that I know far too little about the workings of C++.

I use a base class with pure virtual functions

```
class Base
    ...
```

and a derived classes of type

```
class Derived : public Base{
private:
  Foo* f1;
 ...
```

Both have assignment operators implemented. Among other things, the assignment operator for Derived copies the data in f1. In my code, I create two new instances of class Derived

```
Base* d1 = new Derived();
Base* d2 = new Derived();
```

If I now call the assignment operator

```
*d1 = *d2;
```

the assignment operator of Derived is not called, and the data in f1 is not copied! It only works if I do

```
*dynamic_cast<Derived*>(d1) = *dynamic_cast<Derived*>(d2);
```

Can someone explain why the assignment operators are not overloaded?

Thanks!

Comment: You do not have a virtual base class; if `Base` was a virtual base class, `Derived` would be declared as `class Derived : public virtual Base`.  Your base class may have virtual functions.

Comment: I think you are confusing overloading and overriding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to say without seeing the relevant code. Here's an example that works:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
  public:
    virtual A& operator=(A& a) {}
};

class B : public A {
  public:
    B& operator=(A& a) { cout << "B" << endl; }
};

int main() {
  A* foo = new B();
  A* bar = new B();
  *foo = *bar;
  return 0;
}
```

This will print `B` when run.

Things that you might be doing wrong:

1. You might have forgotten to make `operator=` virtual in the base class.
2. You might have given the child's class `operator=` as signature that's more restrictive than that of the parent's `operator=`, so you're not actually overriding the parent's definition. For example if you change `B& operator=(A& a) { cout << "B" << endl; }` to `B& operator=(B& a) { cout << "B" << endl; }` in the example above, it will no longer print `B`.

Answer (score 4):

I have some alternate perspective on the accepted answer. This is basically `More Effetive C++` Item 33. So even though the accepted solution works, I think it is important to bring out the dangers involved in making assignment operator virtual!

```
class Animal {
public:
    virtual Animal& operator=(const Animal& rhs);
};

class Lizard: public Animal {
public:
    virtual Lizard& operator=(const Animal& rhs);
};

class Chicken: public Animal {
public:
    virtual Chicken& operator=(const Animal& rhs);
};

int main(){
    Lizard l;
    Chicken c;

    Animal *pL = &l;
    Animal *pC = &c;

    *pL = *pC;             // assigns chicken to a lizard.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For virtual to work you need the same signature.  So if your `operator=` works on a `const Derived&` parameter in your `Derived` class that doesn't match the one that is working on a `const Base&` parameter in your base class.

This means that you can accomplish polymorphism but you need to have an `operator=(const Base&)` in your derived class to do so.

Comment: Is it allowed to have both operators    operator=(const Derived&) 
and    operator=(const Base&) ?